# What is the best approach to index varchar and date range?

Tags: postgresql, index, date

There is an order table which stores customer information and location. I need to filter the customer's last five locations within the last six months based on order status.

Query as follows,

```
SELECT * 
FROM orders 
WHERE (    status = 4 
       AND receiver_phone = '91xxxxxxx' 
       AND created_date BETWEEN '2017-08-06' AND '2017-03-01' 
       AND NOT (    receiver_latitude = '10.9315615' 
                AND receiver_latitude IS NOT NULL)
      ) 
ORDER BY created_date DESC 
limit 5;
```

EXPLAIN ANALYZE:

```
    Limit  (cost=374121.96..374121.97 rows=1 width=449) (actual time=2151.298..2151.298 rows=0 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=374121.96..374121.97 rows=1 width=449) (actual time=2151.297..2151.297 rows=0 loops=1)
         Sort Key: created_date DESC
         Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
         ->  Seq Scan on orders  (cost=0.00..374121.95 rows=1 width=449) (actual time=2151.262..2151.262 rows=0 loops=1)
               Filter: ((created_date >= '2017-08-06 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (created_date <= '2017-03-01 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND ((receiver_latitude <> 10.9315615) OR (receiver_latitude IS NULL)) AND (status = 4) AND ((receiver_phone)::text = '91xxxxxx'::text))
               Rows Removed by Filter: 4376895
 Planning time: 0.267 ms
 Execution time: 2151.917 ms
```

what are best approaches to optimize this query?

Comment: Unrelated, but `AND receiver_latitude IS NOT NULL` is useless as `receiver_latitude = '10.9315615'` already implies `NOT NULL`. That condition also doesn't match the execution plan (where it states: `receiver_latitude <> 10.9315615`)

Comment: Also, the order of operands of `BETWEEN` is `first AND last`.  The other way around it won't work.

Answer (score -1):

Seq Scan means sequential Scanning, PostgreSQL enum have to enum all records for filtering result.

You should use Btree index. 
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-types.html

> B-trees can handle equality and range queries on data that can be sorted into some ordering